# Redirect only HTTP subdomain to HTTPS subdomain in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

How do you redirect only the HTTP subdomain to HTTPS subdomain in `.htaccess`? The main site is in WordPress and already redirected to HTTPS with a plugin, but the subdomain is a PHP created site. I have looked and not seen a conclusive solution to this on here.

I copy and pasted this suggested code but it did nothing:

```
#Redirect Subdomain
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$ [NC]
> RewriteRule .? https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
> ```

This would create a redirect loop (if executed at all). In order to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS you need to first check you are not already on HTTPS (otherwise you will get a redirect loop).

These directives would need to go in the `.htaccess` in the document root of your subdomain. Or *at the top* of your root (WordPress) `.htaccess` file if the subdomain points to the document root of the main site. The important thing is that the redirect must go *before* the WordPress front-controller.

This also assumes your SSL cert is installed directly on your application server and not a proxy.

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .? https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This checks that `HTTPS` does not contain "on" *and* the subdomain is being requested before redirecting to HTTPS on the same host.

Although if WP is simply redirecting the main domain, then you could do all this in `.htaccess` and simply remove the condition that checks against `HTTP_HOST`. Although if you have other subdomains that should not be redirected to HTTPS then alter the *CondPattern* to match just the subdomain or main domain (and www subdomain). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((subdomain|www)\.)?example\.com [NC]
```

Comment: Why the random downvote? This has shown to be a working solution and should work on the most common configuration. If it's not working on _your_ server then it's no doubt due to other factors, such as how the SSL cert is installed on your system.

Answer (score -1):

Please try one of the followings:

```
you need to edit
    Redirect "/" "https://yourwebsite.com/"
```

OR

you dont need to edit following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Since this is in `.htaccess`, you would need to remove the slash prefix from the `RewriteRule` _pattern_

Comment: Actually for the Rewrite lines, it should work for any requested URL.but,  of course if you write it in the virtualhost of subdomain. at least, I use these lines for my all http to https redirects for domains and subdomains.

Comment: These directives are not in a _virtualhost_ (or _server_) context, they are in a _directory_ context (ie. `.htaccess`). This makes a big difference. In a _directory_ context, the directory-prefix (that notably _ends with a slash_) is first removed from the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` directive. So, the URL-path that is matched _never_ starts with a slash. `^/(.*)` won't match anything if used in `.htaccess`. You need to either remove the slash altogether, ie. `(.*)`, or make it optional `^/?(.*)`.